# Why doesn't my CSS pointer on an `<area>` work in IE and Chrome?

Tags: html, css

When using the following code, my pointer doesn't turn into the pointer cursor when mousing over the `<area>` in IE and Chrome, but it works fine in Firefox. How should I change this so that it'll work in IE and Chrome as well?

```
<img id="fr_main_img" src="image_main.png" usemap="#fr_main_img" alt="" width="700" height="230"/>
<map id="joinReward" name="fr_main_img">
    <area shape="rect" coords="551,178,675,211" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying `cursor:pointer`, you could just specify that is must be handled like an anchor by adding the `href` attribute. I'm guessing that if the cursor needs to change, it is clickable in some way. Try this:

```
<map id="joinReward" name="fr_main_img">
    <area shape="rect" coords="551,178,675,211" href="#" />
</map>
```

Comment: Is it possible that I give it as `href="javascript:void(0);"`, because if I give it as `href="#"` then I don't get the desired output

Comment: Sure it is, the only issue with inline javascript is that it will lead to an error if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a value in the attribute `href`:

```
<img id="fr_main_img" src="image_main.png" usemap="#fr_main_img" alt="" width="700" height="230"/>
<map id="joinReward" name="fr_main_img">
    <area shape="rect" coords="551,178,675,211" href="#" style="cursor: pointer;" />
</map>
```